# ¿Cómo informar el resultado correctamente?

Tags: java

Estoy realizando el juego de ajedrez en Java

El siguiente código debería mostrar después de cada movimiento, la posición de las fichas en el tablero, por ejemplo, Ab para la ficha Alfil-blanca y Cn para el Caballo-negra.

Cuando el juego acaba, el programa informa del ganador y debería mostrar el tablero sólo con la ficha ganadora, por ejemplo, Ab para la ficha Alfil-blanca y Cn para el Caballo-negra y no lo hace.

Dejo a continuación mi código

```
 // Creamos las fichas según la elección del usuario
        Ficha alfil, caballo;
        if (fichaBlanca == 'A') {
            alfil = new Alfil(tablero[filaBlanca][columnaBlanca], 'b');
            caballo = new Caballo(tablero[filaNegra][columnaNegra], 'n');
        } else {
            caballo = new Caballo(tablero[filaBlanca][columnaBlanca], 'b');
            alfil = new Alfil(tablero[filaNegra][columnaNegra], 'n');
        }

        // Mostramos el estado inicial del tablero
        System.out.println("Estado inicial del tablero:");
        Tablero(tablero, alfil, caballo);

        //Manejamos los turnos
        Ficha jugadorActual = null;
        boolean blancoTurno = false;
        while (true) {
            // Mostramos el color de la ficha correspondiente
            jugadorActual = blancoTurno ? alfil : caballo;
            System.out.println("Turno de la ficha " + jugadorActual.getColor() + ".");

            // Pedimos la casilla a la que quiere mover el jugador actual
            Casilla casillaDestino = null;
            boolean movimientoValido = false;
            while (!movimientoValido) {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Introduce la fila a la que quieres mover la ficha: ");
                    int fila = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Introduce la columna a la que quieres mover la ficha: ");
                    int columna = sc.nextInt();
                    casillaDestino = tablero[fila][columna];
                    movimientoValido = true;
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("La casilla introducida no es válida. Inténtalo de nuevo.");
                    sc.nextLine();
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("La casilla introducida no es un número válido. Inténtalo de nuevo.");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
            }

            // Movemos la ficha y comprobamos si se ha movido correctamente
            if (jugadorActual.moverA(casillaDestino)) {
                System.out.println("La ficha se ha movido correctamente.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Movimiento no válido. Inténtalo de nuevo.");
                continue; // Saltamos el resto de la iteración del bucle y volvemos a pedir la casilla de destino
            }

            // Mostramos el estado actual del tablero
            Tablero(tablero, alfil, caballo);

            // Comprobamos si el jugador actual ha ganado
            if (jugadorActual == alfil && alfil.getPosicion() == caballo.getPosicion()) {
                System.out.println("¡El alfil ha ganado!");
                break; // Terminamos el juego
            } else if (jugadorActual == caballo && caballo.getPosicion() == alfil.getPosicion()) {
                System.out.println("¡El caballo ha ganado!");
                break; // Terminamos el juego
            }

            // Cambiamos de turno
            blancoTurno = !blancoTurno;

        }

    }
    
    public static void Tablero(Casilla[][] tablero, Ficha alfil, Ficha caballo) {
        System.out.println("\nTablero:");

        // Imprimimos los números de columna
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int columna = 0; columna < tablero[0].length; columna++) {
            System.out.print(columna + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int fila = 0; fila < tablero.length; fila++) {
            // Imprimimos el número de fila
            System.out.print(fila + " ");

            for (int columna = 0; columna < tablero[fila].length; columna++) {
                // Comparamos la posición actual con la posición del alfil y el caballo
                if (alfil.getPosicion().getFila() == fila && alfil.getPosicion().getColumna() == columna) {
                    System.out.print("Ab");
                } else if (caballo.getPosicion().getFila() == fila && caballo.getPosicion().getColumna() == columna) {
                    System.out.print("Cn");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("0 ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Jose, pregunto, el problema es que no imprime nada, o que no imprime el final de la partida?. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: arregla con tu ayuda, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Cambios en el primer método:

```
        if( jugadorActual == alfil && alfil.getPosicion() == caballo.getPosicion() ) {
            System.out.println( "¡El alfil ha ganado!" );
            Tablero( tablero, alfil, null );
            break; // Terminamos el juego
        } 
        else if( jugadorActual == caballo && caballo.getPosicion() == alfil.getPosicion() ) {
            System.out.println( "¡El caballo ha ganado!" );
            Tablero( tablero, null, caballo );
            break; // Terminamos el juego
        }
```

Cambios en el método ***Tablero***:

```
            if( alfil != null && alfil.getPosicion().getFila() == fila && alfil.getPosicion().getColumna() == columna ) {
                System.out.print( "Ab" );
            } 
            else if( caballo != null && caballo.getPosicion().getFila() == fila && caballo.getPosicion().getColumna() == columna ) {
                System.out.print( "Cn" );
            } 
            else {
                System.out.print( "0 " );
            }
```

Como puedes ver, los cambios son muy pequeños, en el "detector de ganador", coloqué sendas llamadas a ***Tablero***, pasando, según corresponda, el alfil o el caballo nulo.
Justamente por eso, agregué en las condiciones del *if* y del *else if*, la verificación de entrada nula.
Espero que no se me haya escapado ningún error.

Comment: Marce, eres un genio!! muchas gracias, estaba totalmente ciego.

Comment: Gracias a ti, y no, no soy un genio, desde afuera siempre es más fácil ver los errores.